# Flutter connectivity

Tags: android, flutter, dart, networking, wifi

I want to make application to find SSID (name of wifi) that we connect on it
I try connectivity , internet_connection_checker, internet_connection_checker_plus class but it not worked.
they are not get the name of wifi just check the connection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use network info plus pluging:
https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus

For use:

```
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';
final info = NetworkInfo();
final wifiName = await info.getWifiName();
```